# which ubuntu version would be stable for my notebook?

Tags: ubuntu, intel-core-i5

I have sony vaio laptop with intel i5 2nd generation processor. I am bit confused with ... what ubuntu I should install on my laptop. Currently ubuntu 12.04 is latest ubuntu, but I have heard from some one that it is not stable and has few bugs with drivers(sound & audio).

Moreover, i would also like to know what is LTS release. And which 12.04 version (32 or 64 bits) I should install.

Comment: LTS is an abbreviation for ["Long Term Support"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu is very stable in all versions, but if you are looking for an LTS, then use 12.04. It will support whatever hardware (within reason) that you throw at it.

Regarding the bitness of the OS, it should match the bitness of the machine (32 bit machine => 32 bit OS, and same for 64bit).

Comment: 11.10, is NOT a LTS. Use 12.04, it is LTS, and the latest release. It has been out since April, so any major problems are fixed by now.

Answer (score 0):

[LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) = Long Term Support

The LTS release are supported with updates (like security patches and patches for grave bugs) for a long timespan. For example 2 years for desktop version, five years for server versions.
With the latest LTS-release, both version have 5 years support.

On the desktop you'd often change the most up-to-date release, so long-term shouldn't matter that much. But if you like really like a rock-solid desktop system you should stick to LTS.

Regarding 32-Bit or 64-Bit:
 1. depends on your CPU: 64-Bit capable or not
 2. depends on the amount of RAM in your system

- If your system has a 32-Bit CPU: 32-Bit.
- If your system has a 64-Bit CPU and less than 4GB RAM: you can choose
- If your system has a 64-Bit CPU and 4GB RAM (or more): 64-Bit